# disk showing busy

Tags: centos, lvm, partition

Want to create LV Group but when i unmount /dev/sda5 this showing

```
     [root@xen01 ~]#  umount /dev/sda5
     umount: /: device is busy
     umount: /: device is busy
```

This means disk /dev/sda5 is busy and due to this i can't create phsical,logical volume on this disk.

```
     [root@xen01 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sda5
     Can't open /dev/sda5 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?
```

please anyone can tell me how i do this task it's urgent..?

Comment: Well, what do you have mounted there?  Try `mount | grep sda5`

Comment: out put showing                                                         [root@xen01 ~]# mount | grep sda5
/dev/sda5 on / type ext3 (rw)

Comment: `sda5` is mounted as the root directory of your filesystem.  You are not going to be able to use that partition without resizing the filesystem and then altering the partition sizes (read: adding another partition).  That's risky at best when you're dealing with a normal filesystem, and utter insanity when you're dealing with the root filesystem.  You need to reconsider your plan.

Comment: mount |grep /dev/sda
/dev/sda5 on / type ext3 (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /tmp type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)                                this  showing root / directory is mounted on this drive how i can umount root from here?

Comment: ok thanx i'll try to resize this partition.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the comments in your question, it is showing that `/` is where `/dev/sda5` is mounted. You're not going to be able to unmount the root filesystem, because it will always be busy as long as the system is booted from the `/dev/sda5` partition. You can use a LiveCD to edit the partition to your liking, or boot into another Linux partition if you have one and then edit the partition.